# add click event to auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

this is my AutoComplete code :

```
<link href="JostejuFile/css/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="JostejuFile/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="JostejuFile/scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").autocomplete("Handler/Search_CS.ashx", {
        width: 200,
        formatItem: function (data, i, n, value) {
            return "<img  style = 'width:50px;height:50px' src='PRupload/" + 
            value.split("-")[1] + "'/>" + value.split("-")[0];
        },

        formatResult: function (data, value) {
            return value.split("-")[0];
        }
    });
});
</script> 

<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want to fire an event on the click or selection of an item from the autocomplete list.Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: You can always search in API doc before posting in SO. In this way, you can explore some other useful events/methods as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I did it befor posting but nothing happened. I want to get a new page redirects

Answer (score 0):

You can always add code for select event in autocomplete:

i.e.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  select: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Reference:
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: thanks for your reply but I did it befor posting but nothing happened. I want to get a new page redirects

Comment: can you post your code to show how did you try? or, just prepare a fiddle.

Comment: Here is download link for this module https://www.dropbox.com/s/ckyg76cmbocflpt/CS.rar?dl=0

Comment: No need to share module,just post how are you trying to redirect upon select autocomplete options.

Comment: are you able to fetch items for autocomplete list?